# Word to describe this behavior: applying your work habit even when you're not working?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: I'm an engineer on a vacation. When someone mentioned a machine that's broken, I can't help but join in an try to debug the issue.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Déformation_professionnelle ?

Comment: There's a British expression 'busman's holiday', meaning spending your vacation doing what you would do at work.

Comment: . . . .  still in work-mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you automatically try to fix a problem when you're not at work because you're so used to always fixing problems when you *are* at work, the behaviour is called [**conditioned**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conditioned):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : determined or established by conditioning
>
> // But, really, people like Padraic — who, having been deemed too mad for even the Irish Republican Army, creates his own splinter of a splinter group — are folks for whom wholesale destruction has become a *conditioned* reflex.
> — Ben Brantley, *New York Times*, "Orlando Bloom and Aidan Turner Are Drenched in Blood in London," 4 July 2018

---

In more applied terminology, there is an entire branch of psychology related to conditioned behaviour, and how that behaviour is the result of conditioning.

For instance, from ["What is conditioning? What Pavlov's dogs experiment teaches us about how we learn."](https://www.psychologistworld.com/memory/conditioning-intro) at Psychologist World:

> Conditioning in behavioral psychology is a theory that the reaction ("response") to an object or event ("stimulus") by a person or animal can be modified by 'learning', or *conditioning*. The most well-known form of this is **Classical Conditioning** (see below), and Skinner built on it to produce **Operant Conditioning**.